# Split string and put in DataTable, find second index number

Tags: c#, string, indexing, split

I have a question about split string and put it in DataTable. How can i know if the second array is a string or number?

I have a text with many string like this:

```
 text : ...
        abc 123 def 1 \"ok lo\" ;
        abc def 1 \"ok lo\" ;
        ...
```

array2:

```
 tmpList[0] = abc
 tmpList[1] = 123
 tmpList[2] = def
 tmpList[3] = 1 \"ok lo\"
```

array1:

```
 tmpList[0] = abc
 tmpList[1] = def
 tmpList[2] = 1 \"ok lo\
```

To find all strings startwith abc i did:

```
        StreamReader fin = new StreamReader(userSelectedFilePath1);
        string tmp = "";
        while ((tmp = fin.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
        if (tmp.StartsWith("abc "))
            {
              var tmpList1 = tmp.Split(new[] { '"' }).SelectMany((s, i) =>
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 1) return new[] { s };
                    return s.Split(new[] { ' ', ';', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                }).ToList();

                 table.Rows.Add(new object[] { tmpList1[0], tmpList1[1], tmpList1[2], tmpList1[3]}); 

            }

        }
```

With this code i can find String startswith abc, split and put in DataTable. How can i know if the second index is a string or int? Becasuse with what i did i have a error with second index and it splits not correcly. I think about `if(tmp.StartsWith(abc NUMBER?))` `else` do the code above

Comment: It would be easier for anyone to answer, if your question is to the point "what you're trying achieve". What's your table schema, why second array needs to be an int ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do String.Split(), all of the values in the array will be Strings as well, so in your example for ABC:

```
tmpList[1] = 123 // this is incorrect as the value is an int
```

This should be:

```
tmpList[1] = "123" // value is a string
```

Then what you can do is try to cast the value to an int, and if it fails, you know it's not an int:

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(tmpList[1], out number);
if (result) {
    // your code for if the value is a number        
}
else {
    // your code for if the value is not a number
}
```

Code example copied from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f02979c7(v=vs.100).aspx).